# Grafana Config - Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, grafana

I want to run a grafana instance with custom configuration and docker compose, but I face permission issues with it.

My config is in: `./grafana/config/grafana.ini`

When I try to run the image with docker compose, I get an error

> logger=settings t=2023-12-21T21:19:12.374400182Z level=error msg="failed to parse "/etc/grafana-config/grafana.ini": open /etc/grafana-config/grafana.ini: permission denied"

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    entrypoint:
      - /usr/share/grafana/bin/grafana-server
      - --homepath=/usr/share/grafana
      - --config=/etc/grafana-config/grafana.ini
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/config/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana-config/grafana.ini
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are the filesystem permissions for your local `grafana/config/grafana.ini` file? I assume the `docker run` version works because you aren't setting the `--config` entrypoint option

Comment: The permissions are set to 777 for the whole config directory.

Comment: I didn't ask about directory permissions

Comment: Ok, I checked, I also get the same error just with the docker CLI when I include --config. And everyone can read and write the: grafana/config/grafana.ini file.

Comment: "My config is in: `./grafana/config/grafana.ini`": in the docker compose file it is set to `--config=/etc/grafana-config/grafana.ini`. Is this just a typo (`grafana-config` instead `config`)?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but in my docker-compose.yaml file I tell docker to mount the directory `./grafana/config` to the docker virtual file system under the path `/etc/grafana-config/`. So this should work?

Comment: I figured out that the problem was with SELinux. I will make a nice solution and post it but thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error is because of SELinux on Red Hat based distros or AppArmor on Debian based distros. Thus, I use Red Hat I will only describe here the solution to SELinux.

First, you can check if SELinux is the problem by disabling it:
`setenforce 0`

If you now can add not named volumes to docker, you successfully located the problem. Now you can disable it for a docker container, just add this argument:
`--security-opt label:disable`

You can also just disable SELinux just for some directories for that I have linked the source where you can check out some deeper explanations and examples.

Credits: [Datadog](https://securitylabs.datadoghq.com/articles/container-security-fundamentals-part-5/)